# MySQL: referencing foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to reference a foreign key to its parent key in mysql and i get an awkward error.

I have tried the following.

```
ALTER TABLE `website`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `website_cms_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`cms_id`) REFERENCES `cms_technology` (`ID`);
```

also

```
ALTER TABLE website ADD FOREIGN KEY (cms_id) REFERENCES cms_technology (ID)
```

And I get the following error.

*#1005 - Can't create table 'script.#sql-5203_110b8ba' (errno: 150)*

The following is my tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cms_technology` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cms_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cms_description` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

INSERT INTO `cms_technology` (`ID`, `cms_name`, `cms_description`) VALUES
(1, 'Wordpress', 'WordPress › Blog Tool, Publishing Platform, and CMS');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `website` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `website_url` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website_ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website_scanned` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `website_response` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cms_id` int(5)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

INSERT INTO `website` (`ID`, `website_url`, `website_ip`, `website_title`, `website_status`, `website_scanned`, `website_response`, `website_cms`) VALUES
(1, 'http://www.wpbeginner.com/', '', '', '', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0);
```

What im I doing wrong?

Comment: Try ::
`ALTER TABLE website MODIFY FOREIGN KEY (cms_id) REFERENCES cms_technology (ID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the data type of the of column `cms_ID` from table `website` in order to reference table `cms_technology`. The properties of the to columns must be the same.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `website` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `website_url` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website_ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website_scanned` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `website_response` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cms_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,                        -- <<== HERE
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31e8f)

Comment: I thought that would fix the problem, i changed the data type properties to match and still get the same error.

Comment: Same one, but its fixed now, I added KEY `cms_id` (`cms_id`) after the primary key and the constraint worked

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the **KEY `cms_id` (`cms_id`)**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `website` (
      `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `website_url` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `website_ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `website_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `website_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `website_scanned` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      `website_response` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `cms_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      KEY `cms_id` (`cms_id`)
    );

ALTER TABLE `website`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `website_cms_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`cms_id`) REFERENCES `cms_technology` (`ID`);
```

Comment: when you define a foreign key, you don't need to define key on cms explicitly. [**see this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31e8f/3)